# issue creating new db in wordpress mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress theme that requires a db in mysql to store lots of data.

I'm currently working on an installation script to install the theme. I have written a function to create a new db in the same mysql that WordPress uses it self.

Every time i run the script, i get redirected to a page stating that WordPress is already installed. But I'm not trying to reinstall WordPress, just create a new db in the same sql that WordPress uses.

I have also written a function to create new tables, which works fine so I'm sure there is no issues with connection.

**If this helps, here is the function:**

```
function create_db_mysql(){
    require ('con_db_var/db_4216841335655434.php');

$connect = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pswrd) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE theme_db",$connect);

mysql_close($connect);

}
```

I fetch the db info from wp-config.php.

**so in the db_4216841335655434.php:**

```
require ('../../../wp-config.php');

$db_host = ( DB_HOST );

//etc etc....
```

when i call the `create_db_mysql()`, I get taken to a page telling me that WordPress is already installed and then followed by instructions on how to re-install.

any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database creation and table creation are different levels of privileges. Many shared hosting providers will not give PHP the access to create a database.

So you might need to use your hosting providers control panels to create the database.

Comment: Thing is, I'm going to be distributing this theme out to allot of people and i want to make the installation as easy as possible to for them, so i don't wanna be asking them to do anything that they're not sure how to do.

Comment: That's a great point Nav. I would humbly suggest you should try to find a way to accomplish your target by adding tables to the original database created for wordpress. Instead of creating a brand new database. Having one database would actually simplify the back up process for the user as well. Maybe you can differentiate your own tables by using your own naming convention like `"nav_theme_table1, nav_theme_table2"` etc...